# Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

I get this error on the [key] of `<string>this.errors[key] || key))`

I don't know why, can someone please explain to me why I get this error and provide a solution to it.

```
export class LinqChipsComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck, ControlValueAccessor {
@Input() label = '';
@Input() placeholder = '';
 @Input() options: Options[] = [];
 @Input() selectedOptions: Options[] = [];
 @Input() floatLabel: FloatLabelType = 'auto';
 @Input() hint!: string | undefined;
 @Input() public required = false;
 @Input()
 public disabled = false;

@Input()
 public data: string | undefined;

 private errorMessages = new Map<string, () => string>();

 public onChangeFn = (_: any) => {};

 public onTouchedFn = () => {};

 @ViewChild('optionInput') optionInput: ElementRef | undefined;

 @Output() onRemoved = new EventEmitter<Options>();
 @Output() selectedOptionsChanged = new EventEmitter<Options[]>();

 formControl = new FormControl('');
 filteredOptions: Observable<Options[]> | undefined;

 iterableDiffer: IterableDiffer<Options>;

constructor(private readonly iterableDiffers: IterableDiffers, @Self() @Optional() public 
  control: NgControl) {
  this.iterableDiffer = this.iterableDiffers.find([]).create();
  this.control && (this.control.valueAccessor = this);
  this.errorMessages.set('required', () => `${this.label} is required.`);
  }

  public get invalid(): boolean | null {
  return this.control ? this.control.invalid : false;
 }

  public get showError(): boolean | null {
  if (!this.control) {
  return false;
}

  const {dirty, touched} = this.control;

  return this.invalid ? dirty || touched : false;
 }

  public get errors(): Array<string> {
  if (!this.control) {
  return [];
  }
   const { errors } = this.control;
   return Object.keys(this.errors).map((key) => (this.errorMessages.has(key) ? 
  this.errorMessages.get(key)!() : <string>this.errors[key] || key));
  }

   public registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  this.onChangeFn = fn;
   }

  public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
   this.onTouchedFn = fn;
  }

  public setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
  this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  public writeValue(obj: any): void {
   this.data = obj;
 }

  public onChange() {
   this.onChangeFn(this.data);
 }

  ngDoCheck(): void {
const optionChanges = this.iterableDiffer.diff(this.options);
 if (optionChanges) {
  this.filteredOptions = of(this.options);
   }
 }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscribeFilterOptions();
    }

 selected(value: Options): void {
   if (this.optionInput) {
    this.optionInput.nativeElement.value = '';
  }
if (!this.selectedOptions.find((x) => x.text === value.text)) {
  this.selectedOptions.push(value);
  this.selectedOptionsChanged.emit(this.selectedOptions);
   }
}

private subscribeFilterOptions() {
  this.filteredOptions = this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
  map((value: string | Options) =>
    value && typeof value === 'string' ? this.options.filter((o) => 
   o.text.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) : this.options.slice()
      )
    );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you type the key as string..?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How do you do that? Can you show an example.

Comment: this.errors).map((key: string) =>

Comment: You mean something like this: return Object.keys(this.errors).map((key:string) => (this.errorMessages.has(key) ? this.errorMessages.get(key)!() : <string>this.errors[key] || key));    I still get the same error if that is what you meant.

Comment: can you add a console.log(errors) and console.log(this.errorMessages) right before the failing line? I'd like to see how the errors object looks like...